# How to know which JCheckBox sent an ItemEvent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, listener, jfreechart

So I have

- a *CheckBoxList* class (extending JPanel) with a list of JCheckBox objects

  ```
  public class CheckBoxList extends JPanel {
     List<JCheckBox> checkboxes;
     .......    
  }
  ```
- a *MyChart* class, with a [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) object. 
  Each JCheckBox represents a choice: if checked, to show a dataset on the chart; if unchecked, to hide that dataset. So for each JCheckBox there is a paired dataset.

My idea is that *MyChart* registers itself as a listener for each JCheckBox (it therefore implements the ItemStateChanged(ItemEvent) method). But how can I recognize which JCheckBox has sent the ItemEvent, and therefore hide or show the appropriate dataset ?

Answer (score 2):

You can either set a different listener for each, or you can check the event source

```
Object source = event.getSource() // -- I think this is the right syntax
if (source instanceof JCheckBox) {
    JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox)source;
    if (cb.getText().equals("Checkbox 1") {

    } else if (cb.getText().equals("Checkbox 2")){

    }
}
```

alternatively, you can override the JCheckBox class for each checkbox and just test the source if it is each one.

Comment: What MyClass needs is an int (it means the index of the dataset to show/hide), so I could extend the JCheckBox class and add an int field, so get the event source and then the associated int.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) proposes: check the source of the event.

Comment: Can't be used in my case, because I have a list of n JCheckBox and not n JCheckBox fields.

Comment: @Jacopo: Consider `List<JCheckBox>` and `indexOf()`.

Comment: Yeah, but MyClass doesn't know anything of CheckBoxList, it only handles events sent by JCheckBox objects.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the listener to each menu item.

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem menuItem1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Item 1");
menuItem1.addActionListener(listener);
```

Setting the action command on each menu item will allow you to switch on the action command in your ActionListener.